# Haskell record syntax returning a record with specified field value

Tags: haskell, syntax, types, record

I am new to Haskell and StackOverflow. I have a 'database' of books. I am trying to return the list of fans of a specified book.

```
type Title = String
type Author = String
type Year = Int
type Fan = String


data Book = Book { bookTitle :: Title
                 , bookAuthor:: Author
                 , bookYear  :: Year
                 , bookFans  :: [Fan]
                 }
                 deriving (Show)


type Database = [Book]

bookDatabase :: Database 
bookDatabase = [Book "Harry Potter" "JK Rowling" 1997 ["Sarah","Dave"]]
```

I am not sure how to do this. I have tried using the filter function. I would like the below behavior.

```
fansOfBook :: Title -> Database -> [Fan]

fansOfBook "Harry Potter"
["Sarah","Dave"]
```

Comment: Note that `fansOfBook` is applied to too few arguments, in your example; it's missing its second argument, `bookDatabase`. With a list comprehension, you could do: `fansOfBook title db = concat [bookFans b | b <- db, bookTitle b == title]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to do is a `filter` operation on your `Database`:

```
filter (\x -> (bookTitle x) == title) db
```

where `db` is of type `Database` and `title` is of type `Title` which you are giving as input.

That will give you a list of all `[Book]` with that specific title. Now you have to extract out the `Fan` from it using a `map` function. But note that this will give you a type of `[[Fan]]` as you can have multiple entries with the same title. So, you have to apply `concat` to get them as `[Fan]`. The function `concat` will concatenate the list of lists into a singe list.